# loop though array and see if an element is blank and output html if not blank

Tags: php, html

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 139
        [name] => Eithne Maun
        [contactNo] => 877692398
        [email] => eithne@yahoo.co.uk
        [address] => 
        [county] => Cork
        [country] => Ireland
        [sourceOfContact] => Phone
        [type] => Corporate
        [dateAdded] => 2012-11-26
        [companyName] => 
        [dateOfBirth] => 
    )
```

)

I want to loop through each element in the array and only display the lines below if the value is not blank

```
Number: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['contactNo']);?><br />
Email: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['email']);?><br />
Address: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['address']);?><br />
County: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['county']);?><br />
Country: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['country']);?><br />
Type of Contact: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['type']);?><br />
Company Name: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['companyName']);?><br />
Date of Birth: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['dateOfBirth']);?><br />
```

Is there a function with a loop that i could use??

Answer (score 1):

```
$fields = array(
'Number' => 'contactNo',
'Email' => 'email',
'Address' => 'address',
'County' => 'county',
'Country' => 'country',
'Type of Contact' => 'type',
'Company Name' => 'companyName',
'Date of Birth' => 'dateOfBirth');

foreach ($fields as $key => $val)
{
    if (!empty($contact[0][$val]))
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $contact[0][$val] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
if(!empty($contact[0]['contactNo'])) { ?>
   Number: <?php htmlout($contact[0]['contactNo']);?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$record = array_filter($contact[0]);
```

Then loop through each entry in $record and all the empty entries will already have been filtered out

but watch out as a 0 numeric value is considered empty as well when using array_filter like this